# How to make local repo to local remote?

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

I have two computers; one at work and the other one at home. 
I have two local repos on each of them connecting to central repo.
Is it possible to have a remote between two local repos without interfering central repo?
The central repo belongs to the company and I dont want to push to it until the feature is done
according to [Atlasin git tutorial](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/syncing/git-remote). It should be doable

Comment: dropbox (or other) your working folder.

Comment: If you can access your two computer through ssh then you can do it the way it is explained in that Atlasin git tutorial.

Comment: @SiggiSv: May you explain more, please?
Adding remote is like
git remote add name URL

Comment: @MattHolbrook-Bull: It's a nice suggestion but not professional one

Comment: @AliSaberi IF you have `ssh` access to your two computers then you can do it using the URLs you use when accessing those two computers. If you don't have `ssh` access to those two computers then it can't be done.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you need two or more repos, for that use [git-remote](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote).

There's already [a question about this here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/849308/pull-push-from-multiple-remote-locations), so you may find more info there.

Comment: why -? chould i answer it in comment if it's a duplicate?